# How to do an AND statement in amongst nested IF statements

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, error, calculated-column-formula

I currently have a calculated column that involves several nested IF statements:

[image]

I need to basically, within an IF statement, do an AND statement so two column conditions need to be met.

I've looked at similar answers with the given format below as an answer, however, even though it lets me save the column it does not work (i.e. it does not take off the score even if the column conditions are met).

Any ideas? I'm in Australia.

[image]

Comment: ORIGINAL QUERY

=1-IF([Customer details updated where required]="No",0.15,0)-IF([Data entry impact]="Indirect customer impact",0.1,0)-IF([Data entry impact]="Direct customer impact",0.15,0)-IF([Process impact]="Internal impact",0.1,0)-IF([Process impact]="Customer impact",0.15,0)-IF([DR - Commentary completed correctly]="No",0.15,0)

Comment: ATTEMPTED QUERY:
=1-IF([Customer details updated where required]="No",0.15,0)-IF(AND[Data entry was correct]="No",[Data entry impact]="Indirect customer impact"),0.1,0)-IF(AND[Data entry was correct]="No",[Data entry impact]="Direct customer impact"),0.15,0)-IF(AND([Correct Process]="No",[Process impact]="Internal impact"),0.1,0)-IF(AND[Correct process]="No",[Process impact]="Customer impact"),0.15,0)-IF([DR - Commentary completed correctly]="No",0.15,0)

Answer (score 1):

You have to properly open/close the parentheses for AND function like `AND(condition_1, condition_2, condition_3)`.

Try using below formula for your SharePoint calculated column:

```
=1-IF([Customer details updated where required]="No",0.15,0)-IF(AND([Data entry was correct]="No",[Data entry impact]="Indirect customer impact"),0.1,0)-IF(AND([Data entry was correct]="No",[Data entry impact]="Direct customer impact"),0.15,0)-IF(AND([Correct Process]="No",[Process impact]="Internal impact"),0.1,0)-IF(AND([Correct process]="No",[Process impact]="Customer impact"),0.15,0)-IF([DR - Commentary completed correctly]="No",0.15,0)
```

**Notes**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Use correct *display name* of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
3. Wrap column names inside `[]` if your column name has space in it. For example: `[My Column Name]`.